How can I build a nuget package to support a range of dependency versions?
So I have a nuget package and two intra-org dependent consumers. My First consumer uses Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1, and the second consumer uses Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1.
The second consumer is actually a very large codebase with many projects, updating to 13.0.1 or adding binding redirects everywhere would be a suite wide regression testing effort for them that they do not have time for before organizational deadlines. As the most expedient option I updated our csproj to include two different build configurations, Release and ReleaseCompatibility, roughly like so
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release<consumer2>Compatibility'">
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

The above seems kind of clunky -- needing to build my package twice with two different versions is one thing, but imagine I had a whole host of consumers who needed different package versions, maintaining multiple build versions would be a huge pain.
I know I can use wildcards for minor versions, like <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.*" /> which would have worked if my consumers used the same major version; but I don't think I could very well put a wild card as the major version -- that would be far too broad.
Is there any way I could do something like
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1 - 13.0.1" />

in order to explicitly declare "The features of this library I'm consuming are consistent enough between version 11.0.1 and 13.0.1 that I can consume any of them so I can be compatible with a range of consumers without having to build multiple versions"?
(for reference, I checked out Microsoft's docs on supporting multiple frameworks and noticed it had a section on declaring dependencies, but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, as for now everything is on the same framework version; my google-fu is failing me for how to handle a range of dependencies)

Compile with 11 and let the customers do assembly binding to higher if they need

You should be able to do something like this:
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version=[11.0.1,13.0.1]" />

Or to accept everything less than 14, the upper bound can be exclusive:
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version=[11.0.1,14)" />

See NuGet Package Version Reference for details; in particular the section on version ranges.

This is exactly what I needed! I do wish that it would build and prefer the highest version instead of the lowest; but I suppose I can use it to say "we need to support x version because of y team, go after them to update and then we can update" without breaking our build entirely.
